# Styling the sectionIndexer

Tags: android, listview, fastscroll

Has anyone found a way to style the widget that appears when SectionIndexer is used? Styling changes such as changing the text color or the background color.

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/using-alphabetindexer-for-fastscrolling-listview-t10282-15.html)

You have to create a theme and apply it to an activity

Comment: No need to apply a theme to the whole Activity, please see the other answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

i've found an answer here:

https://gist.github.com/DHuckaby/d6b1d9c8e7f9d70c39de

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

    public CustomListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.CustomListView), attrs);
    }
}
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomListView" parent="@style/GlobalTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?android:textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```